# Java HashMap inside ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

How can I get the value of HashTable inside the arrayList?

I have the following code:

```
public ArrayList resultSetToArrayList(ResultSet rs) {

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();
        int rowcount = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            Hashtable row = new Hashtable();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
                row.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getString(i));
            }
            list.add(rowcount, row);
            rowcount++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: HashMap != HashTable, please update your title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be using [`raw types`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) instead of a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). I think you're asking for something like

```
public List<Map<String, String>> resultSetToArrayList(ResultSet rs) {
    List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Map<String, String> row = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
                row.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getString(i));
            }
            list.add(row);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

As for getting the values back out of a `Map`, you might iterate the [`Map.keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) like

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
  System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", key, map.get(key));
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can I get the values of Map inside the arrayList?

Comment: -1 - suggests improvements, but doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: How about `list.get(rowNumber).get(fieldName)`?

Comment: @KentTipan You call [`Map.values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29), [`Map.entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) or [`Map.keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)

Comment: @immibis Edited. And I wasn't sure if OP wanted to know how to make it a `Map` or how to iterate the `Map` or both. I now explain both.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch need a little more suggestion. hmm. how can I get the Map that i will iterate from ArrayList?

Comment: @KentTipan Use another `for-each`. `for (Map<String,String> map : list)`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have error in foreach, incompatible type; Object cannot be converted to Map<String, String>

Comment: @KentTipan Please stop using Raw Types!